# Why can't I change the identity of this account in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: team-foundation-server

I'm trying to migrate the collections from one Team Foundation Server to another.

A collection that uses local account memberships fails to get attached to the new server. The other collections use domain accounts and get attached without any problem.

So, I identified the accounts with `tfsconfig identities`

Then, I attempted to change the identities by using the following command:

```
tfsconfig identities /change /fromdomain:MACHINE_NAME /todomain:DOMAIN_NAME
 /account:LOCAL_ACCOUNT_NAME /toaccount:DOMAIN_ACCOUNT_NAME
```

But, the operation fails with the following error:

> ```
> Account Name                      Exists (see note 1)  Matches (see note 2) 
> DOMAIN_NAME\DOMAIN_ACCOUNT_NAME   True                 False
> ```
>
> 0 security identifier(s) (SIDs) were changed in Team Foundation Server.
>
> (1) The Exists column indicates whether the listed account exists in
>   Windows. For the List mode of the command, this is the account stored
>   in Team Foundation Server. For the Change mode, it is the target of
>   the change.
>
> (2) The Matches column indicates whether the SID stored in Team
>   Foundation Server matches with Windows.

When I run `tfsconfig identities`, I can see both:

```
MACHINE_NAME\LOCAL_ACCOUNT_NAME       True                 True
DOMAIN_NAME\DOMAIN_ACCOUNT_NAME       True                 True
```

So, why is it still failing? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the account using the "tfsconfig accounts" command.